# ubuntu 19.04 not detecting external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I just upgraded to 19.04 and my docking station with 2 monitors connected to it will not display anymore. Here is my xrandx output:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
    eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
       1920x1080     60.00 +  59.97*   59.96    59.93  
       1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
       1600x1024     60.17  
       1400x1050     59.98  
       1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
       1280x1024     60.02  
       1440x900      59.89  
       1400x900      59.96    59.88  
       1280x960      60.00  
       1440x810      60.00    59.97  
       1368x768      59.88    59.85  
       1360x768      59.80    59.96  
       1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
       1152x864      60.00  
       1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
       1024x768      60.04    60.00  
       960x720       60.00  
       928x696       60.05  
       896x672       60.01  
       1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
       960x600       59.93    60.00  
       960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
       800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
       840x525       60.01    59.88  
       864x486       59.92    59.57  
       800x512       60.17  
       700x525       59.98  
       800x450       59.95    59.82  
       640x512       60.02  
       720x450       59.89  
       700x450       59.96    59.88  
       640x480       60.00    59.94  
       720x405       59.51    58.99  
       684x384       59.88    59.85  
       680x384       59.80    59.96  
       640x400       59.88    59.98  
       576x432       60.06  
       640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
       512x384       60.00  
       512x288       60.00    59.92  
       480x270       59.63    59.82  
       400x300       60.32    56.34  
       432x243       59.92    59.57  
       320x240       60.05  
       360x202       59.51    59.13  
       320x180       59.84    59.32  
    DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Did you figure it out yet? I also have dual external monitor connected to a Dell Dock. When the dock is plugged in Ubuntu would stuck at the screen showing services loading progress. It boots well though when dock is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with:

- DELL XPS 9370
- DELL TB16 Docking station
- DELL UPD2516 Monitor

Monitor was not detected after upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04. Reboot did not fix it. After **reconnect (cables)** from Laptop to the Dockingstation and from the Dockingstation to the Monitor it worked again ... not sure if it was an issue of the Dockingstation, Monitor or of the Laptop.

Comment: I have the same problem but it totally depends which cables are plugged in at which time. Also, seems to lose monitors when they are rearranged in the display preferences? Had all three going for a second, but using 2 now (laptop and attached monitor)