# External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 19.04 with 'nomodeset'

Tags: grub2, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am trying to use an external monitor with Ubuntu 19.04, installed on an ASUS Zenbook 14.

My problem is very similar to this one: [External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)

and
[ubuntu 19.04 not detecting external monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135293/ubuntu-19-04-not-detecting-external-monitors)

But I guess with a problem. I am running the system by overriding some drivers ('nomodeset' set on GRUB options).

Also the xrandr output is very different

```
giulio@giulio-ZenBook-UX431FN:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Could you suggest any solution? 
Shall I follow the other discussions?

Best, thanks
Giulio

Comment: `nomodeset` is just a temporary workaround intended to boot a generic video mode that always works. It's useful in your case to be able to install Nvidia graphics drivers. But after that it should be removed as it prevents loading the very drivers you just installed.

Comment: may I know which CPU your laptop uses? If AMD, then probably the same situation with me :P You may need AMD Integrated GPU Driver. Here is the solution I found: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244376/cant-get-internal-and-external-monitor-working-simultaneously-with-20-04-on-lap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244376/cant-get-internal-and-external-monitor-working-simultaneously-with-20-04-on-lap)