# How to work with two external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, hdmi, 19.04, usb-c

While [ubuntu 19.04 not detecting external monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135293/ubuntu-19-04-not-detecting-external-monitors),
what do you prefer how to go forward?

1. installing 18.10?
2. any other idea?

I have a DELL XPS with similar Docking station (connected with USB-C) and found an [article at DELL](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649)
but installing the downloaded 18.10 driver on 19.04 does not work.

`lspci | grep NVI` shows the NVIDIA and `lsusb | grep Display` shows both HDMI Output channels.

**Requested info:**
for nvidia I use the 418 driver as installed by the system. will check to use 390 driver

Has anyone an idea? Or do I have to install 18.10 again?

Comment: Which nvidia driver are you using? eg if `418` you can try `396` or `390` and one of them ***may*** work.

Comment: @Rainer Hartwig. Please review [how to format questions on this site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/lets-agree-on-some-commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines). Also Please don't revert legitimate edits to your post, code and terminal snippets should be formatted using backticks.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please respond to requests for information by [edit]ing your question. I've done it for you this time. Please reserve the Answer box for [actual answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)